# exporting objects from visual studio 2019 while debugging

Tags: object, debugging, export, visual-studio-2019

Previously Ive used Object Exporter to export object content to various formats to aid in debugging, it helped enormously.  Unfortunately it wont work in vs2019.  Does anyone know of a similar tool that will work in vs2019 ?

Answer (score 1):

Update 2022:

I've published free and open-source extension [Object Dumper](https://github.com/ycherkes/ObjectDumper) for [Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YevhenCherkes.YellowFlavorObjectDumper) and [Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YevhenCherkes.object-dumper) under the MIT license.

"**Dump as**" commands are available via context menu in the **Code** and **Immediate** windows.

It's exporting objects to:

- C#,
- JSON,
- Visual Basic,
- XML,
- YAML.

I believe that combined with the [Diff tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Heku.VsDiff2022) it can be helpful.

Comment: Can we get this marked as the answer. This is very useful for lots of developers looking for the Object Exporter equivelant in 2019/2022 etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is not other tools in visual studio extension marketplace.

Maybe you can download the source code, then rebuild it for visual studio 2019.

Answer (score 0):

You should compile de latest version or simply download the 2019 October compiled version from [this Github comment](https://github.com/OmarElabd/ObjectExporter/issues/84#issuecomment-540138520);

Answer (score 0):

i was able to install on VS2019, by unzipping the vsix, removing the upperlimit of the verions on the manifest.json and extension file, and zipping it again